# Option to control the validation of the jsp:include tag in eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, eclipse-kepler

I have just updated to eclipse kepler (Java EE), but one thing I feel missing is the validation of jsp fragments inside `jsp:include` tags.

For example:

```
<jsp:include page="/jsp/includes/included.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

If I change the included.jsp it does not issues any warning or error in the problems tab (previously it warned me).

It may be related to some validators I disabled, but I could not find after some research.

Where is the option to control this kind of validation in eclipse?

Comment: That's a dynamically executed JSP whose output is included in this page, not a JSP fragment file.  Is included.jsp not revalidated when you do your next Build?

Comment: No, It is not. It have been some time since I made this question, I may try to reproduce again but I suppose it will stay the same. It did not even validated even upon `project -> clean` option

Comment: Does the project's Validation property page ask you to add the Validation Builder? Or if not, show the JSP Syntax Validator as disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project's name go to-->properties -->validation-->jsp Synthax

Comment: That is pretty generic. I have the default global configuration from Eclipse Kepler (J2EE) but It is not working. The previously eclipse version (Juno) had this working by default. What is the specific option regarding this feature inside the JSP syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Window > Preferences > Web > JSP Files > Validation` and make sure that *`Validate JSP fragments`* is checked. This affects your global preference for all web projects.

If its already checked, click on *`Configure Project Specific Settings...`* link (within the same *`Preferences`* page) and select your web project. You can also select your project in the workspace and go to `Project > Properties > Validation > JSP Syntax`.

Check that you don't have *`Enable project specific settings`* checked and *`Validate JSP fragments`* turned off as shown below.

[image: JSP validation off for fragments]

Comment: I have this exact setup and it is not working for Eclipse Kepler, I will try to update and check/uncheck the option to see if it is solved.

Comment: I tried this. Even after updated the validation is not working. Did you tested this on Kepler to make sure it is working properly?